# onActivityResult() returns null data with custom button but works perfectly with onBackPressed() which return proper data

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

First of all I have tried all the suggestions and nothing worked that's why I am asking again.

Background: I am switching between multiple Fragments (Home, History, Tutorials etc.) with Navigation Drawer. One of the Fragment (Home Fragment) contains swipeable viewPager made with Fragments (Level 1, Level 2, Level 3). Now, I am launching an EditTextActivity activity from these Fragments (Level 1 for example) on a button click and returning the results back to fragment (Level 1).

Something weird is happening here when-

I used custom button to save the data from EditTextActivity - Data=null resultCode = 0 but I use onBackPressed() it returns data properly. Why?

Why custom button isn't working?

```
   /*---EditTextActivity----*/

   /* NOT WORKING */
   public void saveData(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("title", titleText);
        intent.putExtra("description", descriptionText);
        intent.putExtra("imgSrc", imgSrc);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

   /* WORKING PROPERLY */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("title", titleText);
        intent.putExtra("description", descriptionText);
        intent.putExtra("imgSrc", imgSrc);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


    /*--- Code inside Fragment---- */



   gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Critical", "Item has been clicked");
                TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.cardtitle);
                TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.carddescription);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditTileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",title.getText());
                intent.putExtra("description",description.getText());
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }
        });


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("RESULTS REQUEST CODE ", requestCode + "\t RESULT CODE:"+ resultCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String rtitle = data.getStringExtra("title");
            String rdescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
            String rimgSrc = data.getStringExtra("imgSrc");
            Log.d("RESULTS",rtitle+"test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might be getting the intent on your first fragment that is the home fragment.

Answer (score 0):

When you start `Activity` from `Fragment` then you must have to write like below.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult("your intent")
```

new check in your `onActivityResult` it will give you exact `requestCode`, `resultCode` and `Intent`.

your `startActivityForResult` be like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourFragment.this, EditTileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",title.getText());
                intent.putExtra("description",description.getText());
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a warning: startActivityForReults may produce NEP. But even if I add this, activity gets launched but onActivityResult doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply but it isn't working if I pass YourFragment.this check this image -  https://ibb.co/qpbjxC7